# Parsing a file in python

Tags: python

Caveat emptor: I can spell p-y-t-h-o-n and that's pretty much all there is to my knowledge. I tried to take some online classes but after about 20 lectures learning not much, I gave up long time ago. So, what I am going to ask is very simple but I need help:

I have a file with the following structure:

```
object_name_here:
  object_owner:
    - me@my.email.com
    - user@another.email.com
  object_id: some_string_here
  identification: some_other_string_here
```

And this block repeats itself hundreds of times in the same file.
Other than object_name_here being unique and required, all other lines may or may not be present, email addresses can be from none to 10+ different email addresses.

what I want to do is to export this information into a flat file, likes of /etc/passwd, with a twist

for instance, I want the block above to yield a line like this:

```
object_name_here:object_owner=me@my_email.com,user@another.email.com:objectid=some_string_here:identification=some_other_string_here
```

again, the number of fields or length of the content fields are not fixed by any means. I am sure this is pretty easy task to accomplish with python but how, I don't know. I don't even know where to start from.

Final Edit: Okay, I am able to write a shell script (bash, ksh etc.) to parse the information, but, when I asked this question originally, I was under the impression that, python had a simpler way of handling uniform or semi-uniform data structures as this one. My understanding was proven to be not very accurate. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: First question: Why do you want to use python specifically?

Comment: This file was created to be used with ansible. And since ansible runs python, I thought that would be the natural choice. Second but not too distant from my first reasoning, if someone can explain how the variable/object assignments work in python, maybe it helps me understand the language, but my main concern right now is parsing the file, more than anything else

Comment: also, the file is used in Linux platform. And I want to parse it with tool available here, not on Windows or AS/400 or OpenVMS etc. Some sort of UNIX derivative tool is desired.

Comment: This is basically a regex operation. I'd probably use `sed`

Comment: SO is not a coding or tutorial service, but I recommend starting out by figuring out how to parse this manually. For example: "I'll open the file, then go through it line by line. If a line doesn't start with a space, it's the name of a new object, so I'll create a new object. If a line has an `@` in it, it's an email. so I'll add it to the current object's owner," and so on. Once you have a reasonable algorithm written out in pseudocode, try to implement it in Python. I don't know what tutorials you've been using, but the [official one](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) is great.

Comment: Is the value of `object_name_here` fixed? Follow some pattern? Are the items under that name indented? Is there a blank space between?

Answer (score 1):

As jaypb points out, regular expressions are a good idea here. If you're interested in some python 101, I'll give you some simple code to get you started on your own solution.

The following code is a quick and dirty way to lump every six lines of a file into one line of a new file:

```
# open some files to read and write
oldfile = open("oldfilename","r")
newfile = open("newfilename","w")

# initiate variables and iterate over the input file
count = 0
outputLine = ""
for line in oldfile:
    # we're going to append lines in the file to the variable outputLine
    # file.readline() will return one line of a file as a string
    # str.strip() will remove whitespace at the beginning and end of a string
    outputLine = outputLine + oldfile.readline().strip()
    # you know your interesting stuff is six lines long, so
    # reset the output string and write it to file every six lines
    if count%6 == 0:
        newfile.write(outputLine + "\n")
        outputLine = ""
    # increment the counter
    count = count + 1

# clean up
oldfile.close()
newfile.close()
```

This isn't exactly what you want to do but it gets you close. For instance, if you want to get rid of " - " from the beginning of the email addresses and replace it with "=", instead of just appending to `outputLine` you'd do something like

```
if some condition:
    outputLine = outputLine + '=' + oldfile.readline()[3:]
```

that last bit is a python slice, `[3:]` means "give me everything after the third element," and it works for things like strings or lists.

That'll get you started. Use google and the python docs (for instance, googling "python strip" takes you to the [built-in types page for python 2.7.10](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)) to understand every line above, then change things around to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are replacing text substrings with different text substrings, this is a pretty natural place to use regular expressions.

Python, fortunately, has an excellent regular expressions library called `re`.

You will probably want to heavily utilize

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
```

Look at the documentation here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Update: Here's an example of how to use the regular expression library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

body = None
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    body = f.read()

# Replace emails followed by other emails
body = re.sub(" * - ([a-zA-Z.@]*)\n * -", r"\1,", body)

# Replace declarations of object properties
body = re.sub(" +([a-zA-Z_]*): *[\n]*", r"\1=", body)

# Strip newlines
body = re.sub(":?\n", ":", body)

print (body)
```

Example output:

```
$ python example.py
object_name_here:object_owner=me@my.email.com, user@another.email.com:object_id=some_string_here:identification=some_other_string_here
```

Comment: Note that regular expressions work pretty much the same whether you use C#, python, sed, or any other tool.